# How do I return a row constructor from a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to return a row constructor from a PL/pgSQL function but it is failing with the following error: Returned type record does not match expected type integer in column 1

Here is a simplified version with a plain SQL function as a comparison. The SQL function runs fine, the PL/pgSQL function throws the following error. What am I missing here?

**Test Functions**

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_sql()
RETURNS TABLE (
    a int,
    b int
)
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    SELECT (1, 1);
$$;

CREATE FUNCTION test_plpgsql()
RETURNS TABLE (
    a int,
    b int
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT (1, 1);
END;
$$;

SELECT * FROM test_sql();     -- OK
SELECT * FROM test_plpgsql(); --error
```

**Error Message**

```
[42804] ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
Detail: Returned type record does not match expected type integer in column 1.
Where: PL/pgSQL function test_plpgsql() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: Maybe the values are being implicitly cast to a different int type or float? Can you try explicitly casting them? Or alias them? `SELECT (1 as a, 1 as b)`

Comment: @JacobH I don't believe there is a way to alias or name the columns in a row constructor. Casting to `int` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular query (returning columns, not a tuple) in `RETURN QUERY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_plpgsql()
RETURNS TABLE (
    a int,
    b int
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 1, 1;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake! I'm very surprised this worked in the SQL version. Really left me scratching my head.

Answer (score 1):

Actually both functions are incorrect. `SELECT (1, 1)` selects a row of one column of the type **record**, not two columns of the types integer.

For some reason this can be implicitly casted in the SQL function. But changing it to `SELECT 1, 1` in both functions will give you what you want for both.

Comment: Sorry, @klin beat you by a minute! This should have been obvious but the fact that it worked in the plain SQL version was throwing me for a loop!

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your design:

1. it is SRF (Set Returning Function), and it is useless in this case.
2. You are using `SELECT` for constant, it is useless too - and it is slower:

```
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_plpgsql(OUT a int, OUT b int)
AS $$
BEGIN
  a := 1; b := 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# SELECT * FROM test_plpgsql();
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ b │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ 1 │ 1 │
└───┴───┘
(1 row)
```